# How to find what instance a method returns? Java-programming

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, polymorphism, instanceof

If I have objects such as:

```
Teacher extends Person
Student extends Person
```

Then, I have a function in a service that returns a List/Array, etc. of Persons, but some items on the list may be a Teacher and some may be Student.

On the return end, I would like to user to be able to check the instance of each element to determine whether it is a student or teacher.

What is the best way to structure this code.

So, in the service I would like something like this:

```
public LinkedList<Person> getPersonByID(List<String id>);
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use polymorphism to eliminate the need for explicit checking the type of the Person. How exactly you do this, depends on your task, maybe you could provide more code.

Comment: Yep, I as well think the correct pattern depends very much on what you plan to do with that information. Sticking with instanceof as instructed in other comments might be good for now but I'm sure you'll find the need for refactoring soon and want to do something more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

This could be solved **without `instanceof` using the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)**. (If the problem is not solvable using ordinary polymorphism techniques, this approach is probably preferred since [instanceof should be avoided](http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html).)

Here is an adaption of my answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148192/java-abstract-method-with-abstract-parameter-and-inheritance/3148343#3148343), with a [demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/UHJJm):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> somePersons = new LinkedList<Person>();

        somePersons.add(new Teacher());
        somePersons.add(new Student());
        somePersons.add(new Teacher());

        for (Person p : somePersons)
            p.visit(new Visitor() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Student student) {
                    student.learn("stuff");
                }

                @Override
                public void accept(Teacher teacher) {
                    teacher.teach("some other stuff");
                }
            });
    }
}


interface Visitor {
    public void accept(Teacher a);
    public void accept(Student b);
}

abstract class Person {
    String name;
    abstract void visit(Visitor v);
}

class Teacher extends Person {

    public void teach(String toTeach) {
        System.out.println("I'm teaching " + toTeach);
    }

    public void visit(Visitor sv) {
        sv.accept(this);
    }
}

class Student extends Person {

    public void learn(String toLearn) {
        System.out.println("I'm learning " + toLearn);
    }

    public void visit(Visitor sv) {
        sv.accept(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an `instanceof`keyword in Java that can be used at runtime to check the type of an object. So, code that read like so:

```
LinkedList<Person> foo = getPersonByID(some_id_list);
for (Person p: foo)
   if (p instanceof Teacher)
      // do stuff
   else if (p instanceof Student)
      // again
   else
      // ...
```

Comment: The use of the InstanceOf operator normally indicates an incorrect use of polymorphism. If we introduce new roles for Person, such as Headmaster, Parent, School Inspector, Kitchen Staff, Caretaker, Secretary, Teaching Assistant - the instanceof operator soon becomes very unscalable, and this multiple if/else instance of checking is very costly.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you need more flexibility later, you may consider moving from an **is-a**  to a **has-a** relationship.

The **has-a** would be a set of *roles* a Person can have, like the teacher role or the student role. Or both, like if a student is giving lectures..

A simple example to show this approach:

---

```
public enum Role {TEACHER, STUDENT}
```

---

```
public class Person {

    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    public Person() {
      // a person does not have roles initially
    }

    public boolean addRole(Role aRole) {
      return roles.add(aRole);
    }

    public boolean hasRole(Role aRole) {
      return roles.contains(aRole);
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

```
public void someMethod(Person person) {

    if (Person.hasRole(Role.TEACHER)) {
      // do teacher stuff
    }

    if (Person.hasRole(Role.STUDENT)) {
      // do student stuff
      // Note: persons may be Teacher AND Student at the same time
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always check if a given instance is type of a given type with the following code

```
        if( selectedPerson instanceof Student)
        ...
```